# How can I extract from a list of pandas dataframes, a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I created a list of dataframes by iterating through multiple csv files and appending these to a list, like so:

```
files = "foldername/*.csv"
content = glob.glob(files)

dataframes = []
for file in content:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(file))
```

**Current output**: a list containing all these dataframes. (I will not display the list here because it is very large).

I would like to extract column labelled as '3' of every listed dataframe. Each dataframe looks like this (this is the first dataframe of the list:

[image of dataframe has been deleted, sorry for inconvenience]

**Desired output**: Accessing column '3' of each dataframe.

**Current (unsuccessful) code**: Here I am just trying to see if I can print column '3' of each listed dataframe.

```
for df in dataframes:
    print(df['3'])
```

Comment: Try using the integer 3 instead of the string "3". It seems your columns are unlabeled and just numbered from 0 to n-1.

Comment: Looks like columns are numbers and not strings... Try `df[3]` instead? What's the error you get with `df['3']`? Also try `print(df.columns)` which should tell you exactly what column names are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first remark, I think you should pass `index_col=0` to `pd.read_csv`.
Regarding accessing the column `3`, this may be a number, thus the following should work `df[3]` or `df.loc[:,3]`

Comment: Just to add to that: If you pass index_col=0 to pd.read_csv, df[3] becomes df[2].

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using df[3] as an integer. Also tried with implementing index_col=0, and I get a 'KeyError: 3'.

Comment: First column has no header, thus pandas names it `Unnamed 0`, to me it looks like an index column. All other columns have a numeric header, starting from 0. Therefore column name won't change. However I see that there can be confusion in specifying index column using a number.

Comment: @Eva try to print `list(df)` to get columns names, and deduce the right format from there

Comment: Yes. I see that by printing list(df), my list contains empty lists/dataframes somehow. So I guess that's why I am getting a KeyError.